# IE8: Pressing 'Open' in Download Dialog saves file to a temporary, non-writable location

Tags: microsoft-excel, internet-explorer-8, vba

I have a specific problem with IE8. Our users download excel files via IE8. Those excel files contain macros which create pivot tables. In order to do that, excel 2007, needs the file to be writable or else the macro will crash with a VBA error.

This only happens when the user downloads the files in question with IE8 and presses 'Open' directly, because IE8 then downloads the files to a "Temporary Folder" which I have not found (it does not seem to be %temp% or Temporary Internet Files, but maybe I am wrong) in which the file is not writable.

When the user first presses 'Save' and then 'Open', everything works fine.

Can someone suggest a work around for that issue?

Comment: `When the user first presses 'Save' and then 'Open', everything works fine.` - the best possible workaround for the case)

Comment: You can use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see where the file's been temporarily saved. %TMP% / %TEMP% or a sub-dir is generally where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. What I've found out:

IE8 renames files on cliking "Open" like `fileName[n].extension` and puts it in temp folder which is not writtable by user.

1. In Excel file name symbols `[` and `]` are not allowed. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213983
   Section "MORE INFORMATION":

   > - Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters: < > ? [ ] : | *.
2. Macroses can be enabled only in writable folder